# How to sum value in foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have a `foreach` loop and I'm trying to sum up all the values produced

```
foreach (var v   in medals)
{
    v2 = Regex.Replace(v.value.Trim('"').ToLower(), "Gold", "100")
        .Replace("Silver", "75")
        .Replace("Bronze", "50");
}
```

I'm trying to add up 100,75 and 50 so total shown would be 225.

Comment: What is `v2`? What do you want to achieve with the output? Why only use regex for the first replace and not for the subsequent replaces?

Comment: _ToLower()_ but then you compare against _Gold_

Comment: As @PatrickHofman says, but more, do you really need a Regex here? What are the original values of _medals_? If they are just one word (Gold,Silver or Bronze) then the Regex is totally unnecessary.

Comment: "Why code does not work" question requires: input, code, expected output plus compile/runtime error messages or explanation of unexpected behavior. The post is missing at least half of the required parts to be good question.

Answer (score 5):

If the elements in medals are simple strings with just the words "gold, silver and bronze" then there is no need to use Regex and a simple if could be more simple to code and understand

```
int v2 = 0;
foreach (var v   in medals)
{
    string temp = v.ToLower();
    if(temp == "gold")
        v2 += 100;
    else if(temp == "silver")
        v2 += 75;
    else if(temp == "bronze")
        v2 += 50;
}
Console.WriteLine("Total is:" + v2.ToString());
```

And if you want to try a single line in LINQ

```
var total = medals.Sum(x => x.ToLower() == "gold" ? 100 : x.ToLower() == "silver" ? 75 : 50);
```

(Not very efficient though, better the usual foreach loop with the ToLower called just one time)

Comment: Dictionary with case insensitive comparison would make LINQ version more compact.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
int total = 0;
foreach (var v   in medals)
            {
                v2 = Regex.Replace(v.value.Trim('"').ToLower(), "Gold", "100")
                    .Replace("Silver", "75")
                    .Replace("Bronze", "50");
                total += int.Parse(v2);
            }​
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply add the current value of `v` into a separate variable declared outside the `foreach` loop, so you retain the sum of all incoming values of v into a variable outside the scope of the loop, as demonstrated in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your medals collection is probably a dictionary(in your code you use inside the loop v.Value),so if v.Value is a string then you could create a dictionary for the mappings with a stringComparer and then use it inside the Sum():

```
Dictionary<string,int> values = new Dictionary<string,int>
                 (StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
     {"gold",100},
     {"silver",75},
     {"bronze",50}
};

int result = medals.Sum(v => values.ContainsKey(v.Value) ? values[v.Value] : 0);
```

This code assumes the medals collection is a dictionary.